# Observed variables in R's lavaan

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling

I am running a structural equation model using `lavaan` in `R`.

The model consists of latent variables, `N1` to `N3`, two dummy choice variables ,`du1` and `du2`, and observed satisfaction variable `SV` (beside the observed variables).

Without the dummy choice variables, this is visually what the model should look like without intercept and residuals:

```
N1 -> observed vars.
N2 -> observed vars.
N3 -> observed vars.
SV <- beta1 * N1 + beta2 * N2 + beta3 * N3
```

Utilizing `lavaan`, this would look something like:

```
N1 =~ SV + observed vars.
N2 =~ SV + observed vars.
N3 =~ SV + observed vars.
```

I want to add the observed choice dummies to the model so that it visually becomes:

```
N1 -> observed vars.
N2 -> observed vars.
N3 -> observed vars.
SV <- beta1 * N1 + beta2 * N2 + beta3 * N3 + beta4 * du1 + beta5 * du2
```

How should I adjust the `lavaan` model in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with ...

```
N1 =~ SV + observed vars.
N2 =~ SV + observed vars.
N3 =~ SV + observed vars.
```

My translation of your description above would be rather ...

```
N1 =~ some observed vars.
N2 =~ some observed vars.
N3 =~ some observed vars.
SV ~ N1 + N2 + N3
```

That is, the satisfaction *depends* on `N1`, `N2`, and `N3`, but is *not* an indicator of all three. And including the dummy variables is straightforward:

```
N1 =~ some observed vars.
N2 =~ some observed vars.
N3 =~ some observed vars.
SV ~ N1 + N2 + N3 + du1 + du2
```

.. presuming that `du1` and `d2` are numeric dichotomous variables. And presuming you're not interested in interaction effects.

Comment: Deuterium - rather than make such extensive edits to the answer, perhaps suggest to lebatsnok those parts be removed in the light of your edits in response to them.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought that when I "edit" someone's post, it suggests the edits to them before it's approved.